# Entering negative fractions in formula mode

Tags: formatting

I find it awkward to enter negative fractions in Mathematica when using formula mode.
For example I need to enter $ -\frac{1}{12}$ in a `text` cell. 
I would press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> to enter `text` mode, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to start [inline math cell](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html) (aka formula mode), then press <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to start the fraction input.

However instead of showing me two small empty boxes for the numerator and the denominator, Mathematica places my <kbd>-</kbd> character inside the numerator box. To work around this, I have to type in a positive fraction with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> first, then exit the fraction mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, backtrack to before the fraction and insert <kbd>-</kbd>. 
Is there a more efficient way to enter negative fractions in inline math cells or in `input` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use expand selection (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) to do this. For example:

<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks!